# How to achieve best browsing performance using Polipo?

Tags: performance, proxy, cache, browsing

I'm using Polipo to browse the web, I've set up the config file as follow (consider  that I have 4 Gb of DDR3 ram, and my computer is quite fast): I've noticed that seems better if I disable the on-disk cache. The following is my configuration file: there something that i could try to change to achieve the best performance? I browse through a broadband connection which is fast enough (the average download speed is about 1/Mb s). Some hints about this configuration? There is also some test online to see if Polipo. effectively, make some difference?

```
### My configuration
### *******************


proxyAddress = "127.0.0.1"
proxyPort = 8123

# If you do that, you'll want to restrict the set of hosts allowed to
# connect:

allowedClients = 127.0.0.1
allowedPorts = 1-65535

# Uncomment this if you want your Polipo to identify itself by
# something else than the host name:

proxyName = "localhost"

# Uncomment this if there's only one user using this instance of Polipo:

cacheIsShared = false


### Memory
### ******

# Uncomment this if you've got plenty of memory:

chunkHighMark = 81920000
objectHighMark = 384000

### On-disk data
### ************

# Uncomment this if you want to disable the on-disk cache:

diskCacheRoot = ""

# Uncomment this if you want to enable the pages under /polipo/index?
# and /polipo/servers?.  This is a serious privacy leak if your proxy
# is shared.

# disableIndexing = false
# disableServersList = false

disableLocalInterface = true
disableConfiguration = true

### Domain Name System
### ******************

# Uncomment this if you want to contact IPv4 hosts only (and make DNS
# queries somewhat faster):
#
#dnsQueryIPv6 = no

# Uncomment this if you want Polipo to prefer IPv4 to IPv6 for
# double-stack hosts:
#
#dnsQueryIPv6 = reluctantly

# Uncomment this to disable Polipo's DNS resolver and use the system's
# default resolver instead.  If you do that, Polipo will freeze during
# every DNS query:

dnsUseGethostbyname = yes


### HTTP
### ****

# Uncomment this if you want to enable detection of proxy loops.
# This will cause your hostname (or whatever you put into proxyName
# above) to be included in every request:

disableVia = true

# Uncomment this if you want to slightly reduce the amount of
# information that you leak about yourself:

censoredHeaders = from,accept-language,x-pad,link
censorReferer = maybe

# Uncomment this if you're paranoid.  This will break a lot of sites,
# though:

# censoredHeaders = set-cookie, cookie, cookie2, from, accept-language
# censorReferer = true

# Uncomment this if you want to use Poor Man's Multiplexing; increase
# the sizes if you're on a fast line.  They should each amount to a few
# seconds' worth of transfer; if pmmSize is small, you'll want
# pmmFirstSize to be larger.

# Note that PMM is somewhat unreliable.

# pmmFirstSize = 16384
# pmmSize = 8192

# Uncomment this if your user-agent does something reasonable with
# Warning headers (most don't):

# relaxTransparency = maybe

# Uncomment this if you never want to revalidate instances for which
# data is available (this is not a good idea):

# relaxTransparency = yes

# Uncomment this if you have no network:

# proxyOffline = yes

# Uncomment this if you want to avoid revalidating instances with a
# Vary header (this is not a good idea):

# mindlesslyCacheVary = true

# Suggestions from Incognito configuration
maxConnectionAge = 5m
maxConnectionRequests = 120
serverMaxSlots = 8
serverSlots = 2
tunnelAllowedPorts = 1-65535
```